# jq: adding nested object to a JSON

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json file containing several profiles:

```
{
  "profile1": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook1"
  },
  "default": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook2"
  }
}
```

I want to use jq to insert another profile, "test", so that the end result will be

```
{
  "profile1": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook1"
  },
  "default": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook2"
  },
  "test": {
    "user": "user3",
    "channel": "channel3",
    "hook": "hook3"
  }
}
```

Directly in the command line I can do it with:

```
cat filename | 
    jq  '.+  { "test": { "user": "u3", "channel" : "c3", "hook": "w3" } }'
```

But when I try it in my bash script:

```
cat "$CONF_FILE" | 
    jq --arg p "$PROFILE" --arg u "$U" --arg c "$C" --arg w "$WH" \
    '.+ { $p: { "user": $u, "channel": $c, "hook": $w } }' `
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.+ { $p: { "user": $u, "channel": $c, "hook": $w } }
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.+ { $p: { "user": $u, "channel": $c, "hook": $w } }
jq: 2 compile errors
```

I've tried surrounding the variable with quotes but then I get just the string $p:

```
cat "$CONF_FILE" | 
    jq --arg p "$PROFILE" --arg u "$U" --arg c "$C" --arg w "$WH" \
    '.+ { "$p": { "user": $u, "channel": $c, "hook": $w } }'
```

result:

```
{
  "profile1": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook1"
  },
  "default": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook2"
  },
  "$p": {
    "user": "user3",
    "channel": "channel3",
    "hook": "hook3"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I have found what seems a temporary solution, converting the object to an array, editing the value (now the profile name is a value and not a key) and converting the array back to an object:

```
cat "$CONF_FILE" | 
    jq --arg p "$PROFILE" --arg u "$U" --arg c "$C" --arg w "$WH" \
    'to_entries | .+ [ { "key": $p, "value": { "user": $u, "channel": $c, "hook": $w } } ] | from_entries'
```

It seems crude, but it works. I am still hoping for a better solution...

Comment: looks like one of the shell variables which you are interpolating is empty

Comment: can you elaborate? When I'm using the same variables as values instead of keys, it works.

Comment: I mean this variables: `--arg p "$PROFILE" --arg u "$U" --arg c "$C" --arg w "$WH"`. Are you sure that they are all set and not empty?

Comment: yes, when using them as values and not keys it works, and they are not empty.

Comment: Hmm. Hard to say. Btw, `cat file | jq ...` is a useless use of cat. It should be `jq ... file`

Comment: If you try `jq --arg foo bar '{$foo}' <<< '1'` (with jq>=1.5) you'll see that `$foo` when referenced as a key expands to `{"foo":"bar"}`. I guess the error you see is related to *that*. Hard to say with correct words. Let's see what others will say

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parenthesis around dynamic keys:

```
jq --arg p "$PROFILE" --arg u "$U" --arg c "$C" --arg w "$WH" \
'. + {($p): {"user": $u, "channel": $c, "hook": $w}}' "$CONF_FILE"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script that demonstrates a solution using [env](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#$ENV,env) to access variables passed via the environment:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONF_FILE=data.json

export P=test
export U=user3
export C=channel3
export W=hook3

jq '
    .[env.P] = {
       user:    env.U, 
       channel: env.C, 
       hook:    env.W
    }
' "$CONF_FILE"
```

If `data.json` contains the sample data this script should produce the output

```
{
  "profile1": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook1"
  },
  "default": {
    "user": "user1",
    "channel": "channel1",
    "hook": "hook2"
  },
  "test": {
    "user": "user3",
    "channel": "channel3",
    "hook": "hook3"
  }
}
```